# Bootstrap 5 how to override "mb-8" for specific element *by adding* "mb-0"?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I've got a quick and simple question.
I have created a form group component which renders,

`<div class="form-group mb-8">...</div>`

components for a project. As you can see, I give `mb-8` to all form groups to add some spacing between them. But I want the last form group child to have `mb-0` so I give a specific attribute to that component which adds `mb-0` to that form group and the end result is like below:

`<div class="form group mb-8 mb-0">...</div>`

I don't want to remove that `mb-8` class from that component because If I remove it, I will have to specify it on each component like `<component container-class="mb-8">...</component>`. I don't want to repeat that in every component except last child, so what I want to do it just write last component child as `<component container-class="mb-0">...</component>` and that will give me a component with no bottom margin.

I can use `m-8 mt-0 me-0 ms-0` combination and add `mb-0` to that class list and have no bottom margin, but that causes every element in HTML output to have at least 4 margin classes and It looks a little ugly. Like below:

```html
<div class="form-group m-8 mt-0 ms-0 me-0">...</div>
<div class="form-group m-8 mt-0 ms-0 me-0">...</div>
<div class="form-group m-8 mt-0 ms-0 me-0 mb-0">...</div>
```

Any recommendations? Or do I have to use that ugly combination..?

Comment: Have you considered using custom CSS and the `:last-child` pseudo-selector? Alternativly within `querySelector` in JS it works the same.

Comment: @tacoshy yes, that's one way to do it. but I didnt want to write an external code for that. Seems like I need to choose either one of your recommendations or that ugly way of doing it with bootstrap.